# Mapstruct: Ignore specific field only for collection mapping

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I am using following mapper to map entities:

```
public interface AssigmentFileMapper {

AssigmentFileDTO assigmentFileToAssigmentFileDTO(AssigmentFile assigmentFile);

AssigmentFile assigmentFileDTOToAssigmentFile(AssigmentFileDTO assigmentFileDTO);

@Mapping(target = "data", ignore = true)
List<AssigmentFileDTO> assigmentFilesToAssigmentFileDTOs(List<AssigmentFile> assigmentFiles);

List<AssigmentFile> assigmentFileDTOsToAssigmentFiles(List<AssigmentFileDTO> assigmentFileDTOs);
}
```

I need to ignore the "data" field only for entities that mapped as collection.
But it looks like `@Mapping` works only for single entities. Also I've noticed that generated method `assigmentFilesToAssigmentFileDTOs` just uses `assigmentFileToAssigmentFileDTO` in for-loop. Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

MapStruct uses the assignment that it can find for the collection mapping. In order to achieve what you want you will have to define a custom method where you are going to ignore the `data` field explicitly and then use [`@IterableMapping(qualifiedBy)`](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/IterableMapping.html#qualifiedBy--) or [`@IterableMapping(qualifiedByName)`](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/IterableMapping.html#qualifiedByName--) to select the required method.

Your mapper should look like:

```
public interface AssigmentFileMapper {

    AssigmentFileDTO assigmentFileToAssigmentFileDTO(AssigmentFile assigmentFile);

    AssigmentFile assigmentFileDTOToAssigmentFile(AssigmentFileDTO assigmentFileDTO);

    @IterableMapping(qualifiedByName="mapWithoutData")
    List<AssigmentFileDTO> assigmentFilesToAssigmentFileDTOs(List<AssigmentFile> assigmentFiles);

    List<AssigmentFile> assigmentFileDTOsToAssigmentFiles(List<AssigmentFileDTO> assigmentFileDTOs);

    @Named("mapWithoutData")
    @Mapping(target = "data", ignore = true)
    AssignmentFileDto mapWithouData(AssignmentFile source)

}
```

You should use [`org.mapstruct.Named`](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Named.html) and not `javax.inject.Named` for this to work. You can also define your own annotation by using [`org.mapstruct.Qualifier`](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Qualifier.html)

You can find more information [here in the documentation](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers).

Comment: @Fillip I have the same the problem. I did what you mentioned above but its not working at all. The impl generated is exactly what is expected with properties excluded in the entity list to dto list mapping. But dont know why its getting executed.

Comment: I don't quite follow what problem you are facing. You should provide some examples of what you've tried and wasn't working

Comment: But how to ignore from source?