# LazyInitializationException with Mapstruct because of cyclic issue

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, mapstruct, lazy-initialization

I have a development project using *Spring Data JPA* and *MapStruct* to map between Entities and DTOs. Last week I decided it was time to address the `FetchType.EAGER` vs `LAZY` issue I have postponed for some time. I choose to use `@NamedEntityGraph` and `@EntityGraph` to load properties when needed. However I am stuck with this `LazyInitializationExeption` problem when doing the mapping from entity to dto. I think I know where this happens but I do not know how to get passed it.

**The code**

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name="Employee.full", ...)
@Entity
public class Employee {
  private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class Role {
  private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
}

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
  @EntityGraph(value = "Employee.full")
  @Override
  Page<Employee> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}

@Service
public class EmployeeService {
  public Page<EmployeeDTO> findAll(PageRequest pageRequest) {
    Page<Employee> employees = repository.findAll(pageRequest); // ok
    Page<EmployeeDTO> dtos = employees.map(emp -> mapper.toDTO(emp, new CycleAvoidMappingContext()); // this is where the exception happens
    return dtos;
  }
}

// also there is EmployeeDTO and RoleDTO classes mirroring the entity classes 
// and there is a simple interface EmployeeMapper loaded as a spring component 
// without any special mappings. However CycleAvoidingMappingContext is used.
```

I have tracked down the `LazyInitializationException` to happen when the mapper tries to map the roles dependency. The `Role` object do have `Set<Employee>` and therefore there is a cyclic reference.

When using `FetchType.EAGER` `new CycleAvoidingMappingContext()` solved this problem, but with `LAZY` this no longer works.

Does anybody know how I can avoid the exception and at the same time get my DTOs mapped correctly?

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-handle-the-lazyinitializationexception/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when the code returns from `findAll` the entities are not managed anymore. So you have a `LazyInitializationException` because *you are trying, outside of the scope of the session, to access a collection that hasn't been initialized already*.

Adding eager make it works because it makes sure that the collection has been already initialized.

You have two alternatives:

1. Using an `EAGER` fetch;
2. Make sure that the entities are still managed when you return from the `findAll`. Adding a `@Transactional` to the method should work:

   ```
   @Service
   public class EmployeeService {

       @Transactional
       public Page<EmployeeDTO> findAll(PageRequest pageRequest) {
           Page<Employee> employees = repository.findAll(pageRequest);
           Page<EmployeeDTO> dtos = employees.map(emp -> mapper.toDTO(emp, new CycleAvoidMappingContext());
           return dtos;
       }
    }
   ```

I would say that if you need the collection initialized, fetching it eagerly (with an entity graph or a query) makes sense.

Check this article for more details on [entities states in Hibernate ORM](http://Here%27s%20an%20article%20about%20entity%20statest%20in%20Hibernate%20ORM.).

**UPDATE**: It seems that this error happens because `Mapstruct` is converting the collection even if you don't need it in the DTO.
In this case, you have different options:

1. Remove the field `roles` from the DTO. Mapstruct will ignore the field in the entity because the DTO doesn't have a field with the same name;
2. Create a different DTO class for this specific case without the field `roles`;
3. Use the `@Mapping` annotation to ignore the field in the entity:

   ```
   @Mapping(target = "roles", ignore = true)
   void toDTO(...)
   ```

   or, if you need the `toDTO` method sometimes

   ```
   @Mapping(target = "roles", ignore = true)
   void toSkipRolesDTO(...) // same signature as toDTO
   ```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Adding @Transactional makes sense since I have to do the mapping after initial fetch. However I do not need to populate the Role bidirectional dependency so it could be skipped at the mapping level if I only knew how. That way the exception would never happen. Unless I receive a answer addressing the mapping that solves this issue I will credit your answer within the next couple of days. PS! The link is missing.

Comment: Link fixed. I don't think I understand your issue with the roles. It seems like you need them, otherwise you wouldn't have the exception. Maybe you are accessing the roles collection somewhere but didn't mean to?

Comment: TO clarify, it seems more the case that something might be wrong in `CycleAvoidMappingContext`

Comment: Maybe if you show the part of the code in it that throw the lazy initialization it can help.

Comment: I do not need it (the call that failes). Mapstruct does the mapping with mapper.toDTO(...). The implementation is generated. I think this is more a question for somebody that knows Mapstruct. Your solution gives me an option to buypass the problem. The problem is this: 1) employee -> 2) has set<Role> -> 3) has set<Employee>. When mapper.toDTO(...) is called number 3 is null. The cycle has to stop somewhere I guess and when the mapping starts the role.getEmployees() is called outside the transaction. I do not need this call since I already have the employee for hand.

Comment: CycleAvoidMappingContext was introdused when everything was EAGER to remedy the same cyclic problem I would think. Might not even need it anymore now when everything is LAZY or maybe I have to do it in another way. I do not know. The cyclic issue is still a factor that has to be solved at the mapping level.

Comment: I think this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42787031/mapstruct-ignore-specific-field-only-for-collection-mapping